# App crashes on a particular layout when minifyEnable is set to true

Tags: android, minify

***Error Message:***

> 2018-12-16 11:08:28.339 7163-7163/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: <package_name>, PID: 7163
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
> at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:406)
> at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:485)
> at <package_name>.view.user.main.a.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$a.a(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$o.a(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$o.a(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$o.b(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.a(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.D(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.y(Unknown Source)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(Unknown Source)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(Unknown
> Source)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:730)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2390)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1298)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:876)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:688)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:623)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:862)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)

I am getting the above error when I use `minifyEnabled=true` in release build.
Building same project in release build with `minifyEnabled=false` doesn't create the error.

The error doesn't appear on app launch,it appears on showing a fragment.

***proguard-rules.pro:***

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}
```

***build.gradle(app) (used libraries):***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.id"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //  Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    //  Support library
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //  Architecture components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

    //  Ads
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'

    //  Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.5'

    //  FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'

    //  Circular imageView
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    //  About libraries
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.2.0'
}
```

Edit 1:
In the fragment which crashes,I have a RecyclerView which uses a custom adapter in which the following line of code is used:

```
viewHolder.userOrderRecyclerViewItemDateTv.setText(MyDateUtils.getDateStringFromLong(Long.parseLong(order.getOrderDate())));
```

**MyDateUtils.java:**

```
public class MyDateUtils {

    private static String calenderToDateString(Calendar calendar) {

        //  Convert calender object to date string
        return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d - %02d - %04d",
                (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)), (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1),
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }

    public static String getDateStringFromLong(long dateLong) {

        //  Create a new calender instance
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //  Set calender time to given value
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateLong);

        //  Return calender as date in string format
        return calenderToDateString(calendar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add proguard rules for the libraries which you add in the build.graddle file

Comment: in my opinion it is not a proguard issue. You are getting a null value for a number, this cannot be null. Add some more code for better debugging

Comment: as you mentioned that it show error in the fragment are you displaying any list in that fragment ?

Comment: there indeed might be a statement similar to `Long.parseLong((String) null);` ... with that amount of libraries, there might be a quite a bunch of proguard rules required, nevertheless.

Comment: try release version with minify disabled and check if it happens again, there is some other issue. also add the class/snippet where the crash is happening

Answer (score 0):

```
    buildTypes {
      debug {
minifyEnabled true  // shrink
useProguard false   // don't obfuscate

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
 }

 release {
   minifyEnabled true  // shrink
  useProguard true    // obfuscate

   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
  android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
 }
  }
```